# How do i replace this <select> element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I have a  element in my form.

```
<select name="states" disabled="disabled" size="10" id="select-states"><optgroup label="Choose State &raquo;&nbsp;">Choose State</optgroup></select>
```

I would like to replace the above select element with the new `<select>` i received from AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'process.php',
    data: 'countryId='+countryId,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 0) {
            //Query returned empty.
        } else {
            //Query Has values.
            $('#select-states').html(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

for example the above Ajax Request gives me back the following HTML.

```
<select name="states" size="10" id="select-states">
    <optgroup label="Choose State">Choose State</optgroup>
    <option value="36">First State</option>
    <option value="37">Second State</option>
    <option value="38">Third State</option>
    <option value="39">Fourth State</option>
</select>
```

Syntax `$('#select-states').html(msg);` does not seems to be replacing the content correctly in `<select>` element. however if i replace it with div it works properly. which is the correct syntax for replacing the `<select>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Just change this line:

```
$('#select-states').html(msg);
```

To:

```
$('#select-states').replaceWith(msg);
```

The way you have it right now it will insert your new select into the old one and you'll get some weird html with two elements with the same id and a select directly inside another, like:

```
<select name="states" disabled="disabled" size="10" id="select-states">
    <select name="states" size="10" id="select-states">
        <optgroup label="Choose State">Choose State</optgroup>
        <option value="36">First State</option>
        <option value="37">Second State</option>
        <option value="38">Third State</option>
        <option value="39">Fourth State</option>
    </select>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'process.php',
    data: 'countryId='+countryId,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 0) {
            //Query returned empty.
        } else {
            //Query Has values.
            $('#select-states').replaceWith(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

The code you have now is inserting the new `select` element *inside* of the old one, which will not work.

Another option is to wrap your `select` element in a container, and set the contents of the container, like:

```
<div id="selectContainer">
    <select name="states" disabled="disabled" size="10" id="select-states"></select>
</div>

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'process.php',
    data: 'countryId='+countryId,
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == 0) {
            //Query returned empty.
        } else {
            //Query Has values.
            $('#selectContainer').html(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, what you could do is replace only the `<option/>`'s within the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` will replace the contents of the item (the `<optgroup>` and `<option>` elements). So that would probably have resulted in `<select><select>...</select></select>`. You really want `.replaceWith()`.

Incidentally probably you could have used Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Inspector to figure this out just by examining the DOM.

Also, sometimes, when you perform this kind of surgery on form inputs, the input will not be re-associated with the form, so its parameter will be missing when you submit. (This especially happens in older versions of Internet Explorer). So it may help to manually re-associate the underlying element with the form, like `$('form#myform').get(0).selectState = $('#select-states').get(0);`

Of course if you really would just like to change the contents of the select you should probably be doing that rather than messing with the entire input. And that will avoid the form-reassociation problem too.