# WTForms: fetch related data

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, flask-wtforms

I have **Flask** and **Flask-WTF**.
I'm trying to implement form, which should change `choices` list for `SelectField` depending on selected value from another (previous) field (and may be with change of set of inputs).

What do I mean .. examples.

**Ex. A.:**

Have initial form

```
Manufacturer: [ ----- ]  // Options are: Ford, KIA, Honda ...
Model:        [ ----- ]  // No options, disabled
...           .........  // Other fields
```

Then user selects `Ford`, and appropriate `options` for model are revealed

```
Manufacturer: [ Ford  ]  // Options are: Ford, KIA, Honda ... still posible to change
Model:        [ ----- ]  // Options are: Focus, Mondeo, Mustang, ...
...           .........  // Other fields
```

**Or, maybe an alt. behavior, ex. B:**

Have initial form

```
Manufacturer: [ ----- ]  // Options are: Ford, KIA, Honda ...
```

Then user selects `Ford`, and `Model` field is revealed with appropriate options

```
Manufacturer: [ Ford  ]  // Options are: Ford, KIA, Honda ... still possible to change
Model:        [ ----- ]  // Options are: Focus, Mondeo, Mustang, ...
```

**Or, maybe a "wizard", ex. C:**

Have initial form

```
Manufacturer: [ ----- ]  // Options are: Ford, KIA, Honda ...
[ next ]                 // button
```

Then user selects `Ford`, clicks `next`, and `Model` field is shown, while previous field becomes a label

```
Manufacturer:   Ford     // Just a label
Model:        [ ----- ]  // Options are: Focus, Mondeo, Mustang, ...
[prev] [ next ]          // buttons
```

---

I have some ideas, how to do that.

1) When user makes selection for (any) field, I make POST request for new form. It's possible, because I make very lightweight application. It's easy to implement, but may be annoying and it's not so good as I want.

2) When user makes selection for field, dependent field's options are fetched from server (json/pson) and this dependent field becomes updated and unlocked.

3) The "C" behavior is the simplest to implement, but it's not for this century

The second idea sounds good .. but I'm back-ender and not very good with js.

---

So .. the question is how to implement such forms?
Any link to good tutorials / docs would be awesome (I've googled, but didn't found any)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two good ways you can achieve what you want.

1. Use AJAX to load the required options based on user choices (as your second idea suggests)
2. If the list of options is not large you could embed all the options as javascript objects and use javascript to load the appropriate ones based on user choices. ex. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent.shtml

The second method has the advantage of faster response from the view point of the user since all the data required is already on the page.

You mentioned not being very good with javascript but I don't think there is another way to do what you want except you can live with your first idea.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It's very useful! I agree, that this shall be done with js.. and AJAX is the best option.. Could you provide any good link for this case?

Comment: .. and as you can see from examples, embedding tree of every possible Manufacturer, model and many other options is overkill, because its huge, and IRL there would be submitted not so much variations.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854656/how-do-i-replace-this-select-element-using-jquery - looks like this is the thing I'm searching for.. I guess, that msg from that question is an html (and not json), am I right?